# Integer solution for $174582x + 1818342y = 54$

Tags: modular-arithmetic

How can I find an integer solution for $x$ and $y$ for this problem type?

I think I have to find a modulo relation between $54, 174582$ and $1818342$, but I am clueless.

Answer (score 0):

Since $54$ is the gcd of $174582$ and $1818342$, we can use the [Extended Euclidean algorithm.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_Euclidean_algorithm)

Comment: Thanks, finally I know what to do.

Comment: As a second comment, when you have an equation like that, you can always simplify by dividing by $2$, then, if possible, by...